# How can I configure a Cisco router via the console using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04

How can I configure a Cisco router via the console using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I Installed minicom but on attaching the console cable to the comport I do not see any router prompt like would happen when connected from a windows machine using putty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you did not properly configure your minicom because it should work. Here is a good document you can follow.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/connect-soekris-single-board-computer-using-minicom.html

Comment: obviously you do not use yum in ubuntu so replace yum with apt-get